# Opencv reconstruction

Tags: opencv

How can I create a 360 reconstruction of a object?

In my project I took 4 photos around a cylindrical object, 90º between cameras. Later I attempt to reconstruct a planar photo around of the object like a panorama, to compare this photo with another.
I tried to use Stitching algorithm. Does anyone know about a similar project or if stitching is the good way?

Comment: stitching is ok, but 90° is probably not enough overlap

Comment: in stitching you must take care that you don't stitch the background but only the object. If there is background in the image, it will probably look strange after blending. The more 3D effects are present on the object, the more distortions will occur, but an appropriate blending will help there. Would be nice if you could post a sample dataset (images).

Comment: I Micka, sorry for delayed the anserw

Comment: I Micka, sorry for delayed the answer. Here is the link :   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7EYN2eMLeFXMjE0R3VNODFneVU&usp=sharing                                                                                                 In this project I like to capture the different parts of the label of the boat shown in the pictures and compose a complete label. And compare this with a correct label.